# React native drawable for both ios & android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

The image icons and certain images in my app are pixelating. I've called simple image path and used image in Image tag and set it's height and width.

Like in android studio we have a drawable folder drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc to support images on all devices.

How can we have something in react native to show no pixelated, perfect images on all devices tab, iphone, ipad, android phone?